# Pentaho: Resume transformation

Tags: pentaho

Recently I ran against a problem. A transformation that causes it has an "Insert/Update" step that operates on a table with more than 200 millions of records. After the connection to the database server has been lost and I re-run the transformation manually it can be seen in the log window that the step re-checks the records it already downloaded before the connection loss. I understand that it's logical behavior of the step. But I have no chance to download all the records. Sometimes the process stops after 15 millions of records, sometimes after 50 millions.
How to deal with that problem? I thought about auto-increment of the primary key value and saving the last primary key value after the connection loss. Or sorting the records of the target table on primary key, finding the gaps and resume the load with the values in gaps. But are there some mechanisms in Pentaho that could do the job?

Answer (score 0):

Pentaho has checkpoints that you can enable for jobs that allows you to restart jobs at the checkpoint that stopped for whatever reason. https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.2/Products/Data_Integration/Data_Integration_Perspective/Job_Checkpoints

However, this isn't something that is available at the transformation level. Your idea about using a sequence, or an auto-incrementing field, is probably your best bet.

Comment: Thanks. I've already visited the link. But I wasn't able to reproduce the suggested action there:
"Right-click a step or transformation in the job, then select Restartable Checkpoint from the menu that appears."
I couldn't see the menu item.